# INSERT... SELECT-ом

Tags: mysql

Каков будет результат такого запроса:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (f1,f2,f3,f4) 
SELECT 4,f2,f3,f4 FROM `table` WHERE f1=3;
```

если строк со значением поля `f1=3` несколько?

Точнее, мне надо продублировать все строки со значением поля `f1=3`, заменив значение этого поля на 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запрос выполнится корректно, только что проверил. Если f1 несколько, то все они добавятся в эту таблицу.

Comment: Спаасибо, я не рискнул проверить, потому что таблица ценная и не хотел ее портить "если вдруг"...

Comment: А Вы для проверки запустили бы свой запрос, закомментировав предложение INSERT. И все поняли бы %-)

Comment: Результат SELECT-а я знаю, но будет ли несколько раз повторяться INSERT при множестве SELECT -вот это не понятно было.